# Не работает transition при использовании box-shadow: inset

Tags: html, css

```css
input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: #80bdff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search task for to do">
<textarea class="add-task__textarea" name=""></textarea>
```

Если в нормальном состоянии у input использовать box-shadow: inset, то при смене тени в режиме фокуса не будет работать transition. Стоит убрать inset и transition работает нормально. Как сделать так, чтобы и transition и inset работали одновременно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[type=text] {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  /* Рекомендую перенести transition в основной класс, чтобы была анимация при потере фокуса */
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: #80bdff;

  /* Указывая box-shadow в :focus идет полная перезапись этого свойства. 
     Соответственно, чтобы осталась тень inset, её нужно продублировать через запятую. */
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: А если мне не нужен inset при фокусе? Ты конечно гений)

Comment: А вот на счет первого совета я согласен, спасибо

Comment: Изначально немного не понял ваш вопрос, ответ отредактировал

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!!!!!!